# How do I make new image views movable?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have been trying to piece together a project that contains a collection view that scrolls on the side, and when a cell is tapped it will add a new image view to the scene. I would like this new image to be draggable.

My code currently shows the collection view and when tapped adds a new image (which I call stickers).

I haven't quite figured out how to make it place the correct sticker yet, but my first goal is to make sure what appears can be moved.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let stickers: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "cow")!,
        UIImage(named: "chicken")!,
        UIImage(named: "pig")!,
        UIImage(named: "cow")!,
        UIImage(named: "chicken")!,
        UIImage(named: "pig")!,
        UIImage(named: "cow")!,
        UIImage(named: "chicken")!,
        UIImage(named: "pig")!,
    ]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stickers.count
    }

    var activeSticker = UIImage(named: "cow")

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.stickerImage.image = stickers[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
        cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        let addSticker = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        addSticker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addStickerTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        activeSticker = cell.stickerImage.image
        cell.addSubview(addSticker)
        return cell
    }    

    @IBAction func addStickerTapped() -> Void {
        print("Hello Sticker Button")
        let image = activeSticker //UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        //Imageview on Top of View
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check Apple’s documentation for [drag and drop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views)

Comment: Hi there. Could you please clarify your main question here? I don't understand what you mean by "make sure what appears can be moved". What exactly do you intend to move and why do you need to move it?

Comment: when a cell is tapped it adds a new image to the scene. I would like the user to be able to drag the new image around.

the scene is basically a farm, and all of the cells are different animals. You get to add them to the farm and drag them where ever you like

Comment: Add a pan gesture recognizer to the imageView, and then you can move it's frame.center.x and frame.center.y with the change in position you get from the gestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the `imageView` around inside `self.view` you can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Add the gesture recognizer, for example, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedImageView: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addPanGestureRecognizer()
    }

    func addPanGestureRecognizer() {
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveImageView(_:)))
        // set up and optimize pan gesture options here if you need to
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    @objc func moveImageView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // assign one of your image views to selectedImageView to ensure you only move one image view at a time
        // for example in func addStickerTapped() you could assign selectedImageView = imageView

        guard let selectedImageView = selectedImageView else {
            return
        }

        switch sender.state {
        case .changed, .ended:
            selectedImageView.center = selectedImageView.center.offset(by: sender.translation(in: self.view))
            sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func offset(by point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x + point.x, y: self.y + point.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it working with your input, thank you! One edit I had to make was changing this line:
            sender.setTranslation(0.0, in: self.view)
to:
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. Should've used .zero rather than 0.0.